# Grep: The asterisk (*) doesn't always work

Tags: command-line, bash, grep, regex

If I grep a document that contains the following:

`ThisExampleString`

...for the expression `This*String` or `*String`, nothing is returned. However, `This*` returns the above line as expected.

*Whether the expression is enclosed in quotes makes no difference.*

I thought the asterisk indicated any number of unknown characters? Why does it only work if it's at the start of the expression? If this is intended behavior, what do I use instead of the expressions `This*String` and `*String`?

Comment: because that is not how regex work... (in particular: `* != any number of unknown characters`. read the doc.)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

An asterisk in [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) means "match the preceding element 0 or more times".

In your particular case with `grep 'This*String' file.txt`, you are trying to say, "hey, grep, match me the word `Thi`, followed by lowercase `s` zero or more times, followed by the word `String`". The lowercase `s` is nowhere to be found in `Example`, hence grep ignores `ThisExampleString`.

In the case of `grep '*String' file.txt`, you are saying "grep, match me the empty string--literally nothing--preceding the word `String`". Of course, that's not how `ThisExampleString` is supposed to be read. (There are [other possible meanings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/742772/what-does-a-leading-asterisk-mean-in-extended-and-basic-regular-expressions)--you can try this with and without the `-E` flag--but none of the meanings are anything like what you really want here.)

Knowing that `.` means "any single character", we could do this: `grep 'This.*String' file.txt`. Now the grep command will read it correctly: `This` followed by any character (think of it as selection of ASCII characters) repeated any number of times, followed by `String`.

Comment: In Bash (and most of the Unix shells) `*` is a special character and it should be quoted or escaped for example like this: `grep 'This*String' file.txt` or this: `grep This\*String file.txt` to not be surprised by unexpected results.

Comment: @pabouk yes that is true, but in `grep`,`awk`, and `sed` wildcard (or asterisk ) is treated differently.   When doing `grep 'This*String' file.txt` you're asking `grep` to do the job, not `bash` , so it will be interpreted according to regular expression rules. Now, `grep This\*String file.txt` is looking for This*String, a text with This , follwed by actual asterisk, followed by String. OP's question was due to confusion between asterisk behavior in bash and grep.  I may include your comment into the answer, but probably later , when I wake up, as it's 3am where i am at :)

Comment: @pabouk in shells, the `*` is a wildcard. In grep, `*` is a regular expression operator. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/57957/70524

Comment: pabouk is right, filename expansion takes place before the command is run; compare `strace grep .* file.txt |& head -n 1
` and `strace grep '.*' file.txt |& head -n 1`. Also actually `grep` works also with any Unicode character (e.g. `echo -ne ⇏ | grep ⇏` outputs `⇏`)

Comment: @Serg: you have a high reputation here so I thought that you immediately notice what I mean. The OP has tagged the question [tag:bash] so I assume the discussed commands are interpreted by `bash`. This means that first `bash` interprets its special characters and only after all performed expansions it passes the parameters to the spawned process. ----- For example this command in Bash: `grep This.\*String file.txt` will spawn `/bin/grep` with these parameters 0: `grep`, 1: `This.*String`, 2: `file.txt`. Notice that Bash removed the backslash and the originally escaped `*` was passed literally.

Comment: The funny (and for troubleshooting pretty nasty :) thing is that your commands like `grep This.*String file.txt` will normally work because most probably there will not be a file matching the shell wildcard expression `This.*String`. In such a case by default Bash will pass the argument literally including `*`.

Comment: ""In case of grep *String file.txt you are saying "grep, match me a blank(literally nothing) preceding String ". Of course, that's not how ThisExampleString is supposed to be read."" for that comment is wrong for me cos, you say match me blank zero or more

Comment: I think it would be more correct to rephrase `The lowercase s is nowhere to be found in Example, hence grep ignores ThisExampleString` to `"Example" is different from "the lowercase s : 0, 1 or n times", hence grep ignores "ThisExampleString"`

Answer (score 9):

The `*` metacharacter in BRE<sup>1</sup>s, ERE<sup>1</sup>s and PCRE<sup>1</sup>s matches 0 or more occurences of the previously grouped pattern (if a grouped pattern is preceding the `*` metacharacter), 0 or more occurences of the previous character class (if a character class is preceding the `*` metacharacter) or 0 or more occurences of the previous character (if neither a grouped pattern nor a character class is preceding the `*` metacharacter);

This means that in the `This*String` pattern, being the `*` metacharacter not preceded either by a grouped pattern or a character class, the `*` metacharacter matches 0 or more occurences of the previous character (in this case the `s` character):

```
% cat infile               
ThisExampleString
ThisString
ThissString
% grep 'This*String' infile
ThisString
ThissString
```

To match 0 or more occurences of any character, you want to match 0 or more occurences of the `.` metacharacter, which matches any character:

```
% cat infile               
ThisExampleString
% grep 'This.*String' infile
ThisExampleString
```

The `*` metacharacter in BREs and EREs is always "greedy", i.e. it will match the longest match:

```
% cat infile
ThisExampleStringIsAString
% grep -o 'This.*String' infile
ThisExampleStringIsAString
```

This may not be the desired behavior; in case it's not, you can turn on `grep`'s PCRE engine (using the `-P` option) and append the `?` metacharacter, which when put after the `*` and `+` metacharacters has the effect of changing their greediness:

```
% cat infile
ThisExampleStringIsAString
% grep -Po 'This.*?String' infile
ThisExampleString
```

---

<sub>1: Basic Regular Expressions, Extended Regular Expressions and Perl Compatible Regular Expressions</sub>

Comment: Thank you for the very informative answer. However, I chose a different answer because it was shorter and easier to understand. +1 for providing so much detail.

Comment: @Trae You're welcome. It's fine, I agree that maybe this was too complex and made too many assumptions for someone not too familiar with the topic.

Answer (score 5):

One of explanation found here [link](http://www.robelle.com/smugbook/regexpr.html):

> Asterisk "`*`" does not mean the same thing in regular expressions as in wildcarding; it is a modifier that applies to the preceding single character, or expression such as [0-9]. An asterisk matches zero or more of what precedes it. Thus `[A-Z]*` matches any number of upper-case letters, including none, while `[A-Z][A-Z]*` matches one or more upper-case letters.

Answer (score 4):

`*` has a special meaning both as a shell [globbing](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) character ("wildcard") and as a regular expression [metacharacter](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html). You must take both into account, though if you [quote](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) your regular expression then you can prevent the shell from treating it specially and ensure that it passes it unchanged to [`grep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/grep.1.html). Although *sort of* similar conceptually, what `*` means to the shell is quite different from what it means to `grep`.

### *First* the shell treats `*` as a wildcard.

You said:

> *Whether the expression is enclosed in quotes makes no difference.*

That depends on what files exist in whatever directory you happen to be in when you run the command. For patterns that contain the directory separator `/`, it may depend on what files exist across your whole system. You should always [quote](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting) regular expressions for `grep`--and [single quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Single-Quotes) are usually best--*unless* you are sure you are okay with the [nine types of potentially surprising transformations](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions) the shell otherwise performs *before* executing the `grep` command.

When the shell encounters a `*` character that is not [quoted](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting), it takes it to mean "zero or more of any character" and [replaces the word that contains it](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion) with a list of filenames that match the pattern. (Filenames that start with `.` are excluded--unless your pattern itself starts with `.` *or* you've configured your shell to include them anyway.) This is known as [*globbing*](https://foldoc.org/glob)--and also by the names *filename expansion* and *pathname expansion*.

The effect with `grep` will usually be that the first matching filename is taken as the regular expression--even if it would be quite obvious to a human reader that it is *not* meant as a regular expression--while all the other filenames listed automatically from your glob are taken as the files *inside* which to search for matches. (You do not see the list--it is passed opaquely to `grep`.) You virtually never want this to happen.

The reason this is *sometimes* not a problem--and in your particular case, at least *so far*, it wasn't--is that `*` will be left alone **if all of the following are true**:

1. **There were *no* files whose names matched.** *...Or* you have disabled globbing in your shell, typically with `set -f` or the equivalent `set -o noglob`. But this is uncommon and you would probably know you did it.
2. You are using a shell whose default behavior is to leave `*` alone when there are no matching filenames. This is the case in Bash, which you are *probably* using, but not in all Bourne-style shells. (The default behavior in  the popular shell Zsh, for instance, is for globs to either *(a)* expand or *(b)* produce an error.) *...Or* you have changed this behavior of your shell--how that is done varies across shells.
3. You have not *otherwise* told your shell to allow globs to be replaced with *nothing* when there are no matching files, nor to fail with an error message in this situation. In Bash that would have been done by enabling the `nullglob` or `failglob` [shell option](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin), respectively.

You can sometimes rely on #2 and #3 but you can rarely rely on #1. A `grep` command with an unquoted pattern that works now may stop working when you have different files or when you run it from a different place. **Quote your regular expression and the problem goes away.**

### *Then* the `grep` command treats `*` as a quantifier.

*The other answers--such as those [by Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy](https://askubuntu.com/a/681646/22949) and [by kos](https://askubuntu.com/a/681648/22949)--also address this aspect of this question, in somewhat different ways. So I encourage those who haven't read them yet to do so, either before or after reading the rest of this answer.*

Assuming the `*` does make it to grep--which quoting should ensure--`grep` then takes it to mean that **the item that precedes it [may occur any number of times](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), rather than having to occur exactly once**. It could still occur once. Or it might not be present at all. Or it could be repeated. Text that fits with *any* of those possibilities will be matched.

What do I mean by "item"?

- A single [character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html). Since `b` matches a literal `b`, `b*` matches zero or more `b`s, thus `ab*c` matches `ac`, `abc`, `abbc`, `abbbc`, etc.

  Similarly, since [`.` matches any character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html), `.*` matches zero or more characters<sup>**1**</sup>, thus `a.*c` matches `ac`, `akc`, `ahjglhdfjkdlgjdfkshlgc`, even `acccccchjckhcc`, etc. *Or*
- A [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). Since `[xy]` matches `x` or `y`, `[xy]*` matches zero or more characters where each one is either `x` or `y`, thus `p[xy]*q` matches `pq`, `pxq`, `pyq`, `pxxq`, `pxyq`, `pyxq`, `pyyq`, `pxxxq`, `pxxyq`, etc.

  This also applies to [shorthand forms](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) of character classes like `\w`, `\W`, `\s`, and `\S`. Since `\w` matches any word character, `\w*` matches zero or more word characters. *Or*
- A [group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). Since `\(bar\)` matches `bar`, `\(bar\)*` matches zero or more `bar`s, thus `foo\(bar\)*baz` matches `foobaz`, `foobarbaz`, `foobarbarbaz`, `foobarbarbarbaz`, etc.

  With the `-E` or `-P` options, `grep` treats your regular expression as an [ERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_extended) or [PCRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) respectively, rather than as a [BRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended), and then groups are surrounded by `(` `)` instead of `\(` `\)`, so then you'd use `(bar)` instead of `\(bar\)` and `foo(bar)baz` instead of `foo\(bar\)baz`.

[**`man grep`**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/grep.1.html) gives a reasonably accessible explanation of BRE and ERE syntax at the end, as well as listing all the command-line options `grep` accepts at the beginning. I recommend that manual page as a resource, and also [the GNU Grep documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/) and [this tutorial/reference site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) (which I've linked to a number of pages on, above).

For testing and learning `grep`, I recommend calling it with a pattern but no filename. Then it takes input from your terminal. Enter lines; the lines that are echoed back to you are the ones that contained text your pattern matched. To quit, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> at the beginning of a line, which signals end of input. (Or you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> as with most command-line programs.) For example:

```
grep 'This.*String'
```

If you use the `--color` flag, `grep` will highlight the specific *parts* of your lines that matched your regular expression, which is very useful both for figuring out what a regular expression does and for finding what you are looking for once you do. By default, Ubuntu users have a Bash alias that causes `grep --color=auto` to run--which is sufficient for this purpose--when you run `grep` from the command line, so you likely don't even need to pass `--color` manually.

<sup>**1**</sup> <sub>Therefore `.*` in a regular expression means what `*` means in a shell glob. However, the difference is that `grep` automatically prints lines that contain your match *anywhere* in them, so it's typically unnecessary to have `.*` at the beginning or end of a regular expression.</sub>