# What does a leading asterisk mean in extended and basic regular expressions?

Tags: grep, regex

What are the semantics of `*` at the beginning of a RE? It is documented ([man 7 regex](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/regex.7)) that for basic REs it matches only `*` (i.e., it turns to an ordinary character), but what happens for extended REs? By examples, it looks like it has the same semantics of '.*', but I cannot find any source for this.

```
prompt> echo "hello" | grep -E  '*'
hello
prompt> echo "hello" | grep  '*'
prompt>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as [the standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04_03) is concerned, the results are [undefined](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html):

> `*+?{`
>
> The `<asterisk>`, `<plus-sign>`, `<question-mark>`, and
>   `<left-brace>` shall be special except when used in a bracket
>   expression (see [RE Bracket Expression](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05)). Any of the following uses
>   produce undefined results:
>
> - If these characters appear first in an ERE, or immediately following a `<vertical-line>`, `<circumflex>`, or `<left-parenthesis>`
> - If a `<left-brace>` is not part of a valid interval expression (see [EREs Matching Multiple Characters](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04_06))

Any attempt to consistently explain what happens in this case would be at the mercy of the implementation. Going by @kos's answer, they probably match the empty regular expression.

Answer (score 5):

Notice that `echo "hello" | grep -E  '*'` returns `hello` because the string is a match and `grep` returns the whole line, not because `*` is the same as `.*`. You should test with `-Eo`:

```bsh
% echo "hello" | grep -Eo '*' 
%
```

I don't have sources to backup this, but a not too wild guess based on a pratical test suggests that a sequence of quantifiers at the beginning of the regex is just ignored:

```bsh
% echo "*hello" | grep -Eo '*'    
% echo "+hello" | grep -Eo '+'
% echo "?hello" | grep -Eo '?'
% echo "{1}hello" | grep -Eo '{1}'
1}
% echo "***hello" | grep -Eo '***' 
% echo "*+?{1}hello" | grep -Eo '*+?{1}hello'
1}hello
```

My prompt prepends the return value at the start of the line in case of a return value different from `0`, so those are all matches.

Answer (score 1):

The `grep -E  'regex'` show lines containing the matching regex and highlights the matches in red color.

taking this into consideration, `grep -E  '*'` will show all the lines with zero or more '(nothing)' in it.

`grep '*'` will just show lines having the star in it.