# Asterisk not working with grep

Tags: command-line, text-processing, grep, regex, wildcards

I searched for `ki` with `*` as per the example below and it should have returned the first three lines. I am not sure why it returns the last line when there is no `ki` matching it.

```
$ grep "ki*" trial_file.txt
kartik,27,Bangalore,Karnataka
pulkit,25,Bangalore,Karnataka
kit,28,Bangalore,Karnataka
kush,24,Pennsylvania,Philadelphia
```

Comment: Run it `grep ki trial_file.txt`. The `*` is wrong.

Comment: @Pilot6 This question involves two misconceptions, and the main one is that `grep` matches the whole line and requires something special to be done to just match *part* of a line. Both [mjb2kmn's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/957102) and [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/957106) address that, but it would be outside the scope of [that question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/681637/grep-the-asterisk-doesnt-always-work). (That question also has a major part that doesn't apply here--the issue of *when* the shell expands `*`--though currently no answers there really address that in detail.)

Answer (score 12):

Don't use `*` for this. Use `grep 'ki' trial_file.txt` or `grep -F 'ki' trial_file.txt`.

1. Unless you pass it the `-x`/`--line-regex` option, [`grep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/grep.1.html) will return lines that *contain* a match anywhere, even if the whole line isn't a match. So all you have to do is match part of the line. You don't have to do anything special to indicate there may be more characters.
2. [In a regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), `*` means "zero or more of the previous item." This is an entirely different from its meaning in [shell pathname expansion](https://foldoc.org/glob) (see also [this article](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob), [`man 7 glob`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man7/glob.7.html), and [this section](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion)). So, for example:

   - `ax*b` matches `a`, followed by any number of `x`es (even none), followed by `b`: `ab`, `axb`, `axxb`, `axxxb`, ...
   - `a[xz]*b` matches `a` followed by any number of characters where each is `x` or `z`, followed by `b`: `ab`, `axb`, `azb`, `axxb`, `axzb`, `azxb`, `azzb`, `axxxb`, ...
   - `a(xyz)*b` matches `a`, followed zero or more occurrences of the string `xyz`, followed by `b`: `ab`, `axyzb`, `axyzxyzb`, `axyzxyzxyzb`, ...

In this case, it seems like you're just searching for text. You don't need to use any regular expression *metacharacters* like `.`, `*`,  or `\` that have special meanings. That's why I suggest passing the `-F` flag, which makes `grep` search for "fixed strings" rather than performing regular expression matching.

If, however, you only want to match starting at the *beginning* of the line, then you do want to use a regular expression metacharacter: `^`, as [mjb2kmn suggests](https://askubuntu.com/a/957102/22949). This [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) your match to the start of the line. In that case you would run `grep '^ki' trial_file.txt`.

For more information on the options `grep` supports, see [`man grep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/grep.1.html) and the [GNU Grep manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html).

Although in general I suggest enclosing regular expressions in [`'` `'` quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Single-Quotes), in this case no [quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting) is necessary because the shell does not perform any [expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions) on `ki` or `^ki` before passing them to `grep`.

Answer (score 10):

I think you're expecting shell-style wild cards here, but what you're getting is a regular expression.
When searching for `ki*` you are asking for a literal `k` followed by 0 or more `i`s.

The first line doesn't contain "ki" either.

How to do this correctly depends on what exactly you are trying to match.

As commented above `grep "ki"` could be what you want, or if you want to match only lines starting with "ki" you'd need `grep "^ki"`.
`^` denotes the beginning of the line.

Comment: It is not a regular expression when you use `grep` without `-E`, but in this case it is really looking for `k`s with 0 or more `i`s

Comment: It actually is basic regular expressions by default, the -E options enables "Extended regular expressions" `man grep` explains this.
Edit: sorry the linux grep man page does not explain this well, the BSD grep man page does though.

Comment: You are correct. I always call only extended regexp the real ones. But it is probably wrong.

Comment: @Pilot6 Ubuntu has GNU Grep, which supports three regex dialects: pass `-G` or no flag for POSIX BRE with GNU extensions, `-E` for POSIX ERE, or `-P` for PCRE ("Perl"). It also accepts `-F` for "fixed strings" where the pattern is matched literally. See [*Matcher Selection*](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/grep.1.html). Only `-F` does *not* use a regular expression. BRE and ERE are more similar to each other than to PCRE and many other dialects; both omit powerful features that are now common, like [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).